# Sum based on multiple scopes in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

There are many brand names, and each brand name has many sources. Each source has many dates which includes a "count" for those values together.

My rows of data look like this:

*BrandName|Source|Date|Count*

Based on that I would like to create a line chart that would have **date** on the **x_axis**, and percent of one source compared to all other sources for that brand in **y_axis**. My series group are the Brand_Names.

Current Category Group is: Date

Series Group: Brand Name

Values:

```
Sum(IIf(Fields!Source.Value="source12",

           CInt(Fields!Count.Value),

           Nothing))/Sum(CInt(Fields!Count.Value), "Chart2_CategoryGroup")
```

"**Chart2_CategoryGroup**" is the **Date**.

This however compares the current source value to sum of all the other sources for the current date no matter the brand name.

*Is there a way that I could include CategoryGroup and the SeriesGroup in the scope of the sum?*

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very commonly requested feature, but it's not possible in report expressions. You only have the option to override the default scope with one particular element. One workaround is to do the intermediate aggregation within the initial query. Another option is to add calculated fields to your dataset that are conditional, but this gets very tedious for large reports.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What do you mean intermediate aggregation?

Comment: @Brenden1995 In other words, you can use SQL subqueries to sum numbers at different levels. That way you have the numbers you need already in your dataset and you don't have to rely on SSRS to determine the scope.